Handle dialogs with Selenium 4 when BiDi is enabled
The BiDi introduced in Selenium 4 sounds interesting.
But when I turn it on with options.setCapability("webSocketUrl", true); I have trouble with Alert, Model, and Prompt. The old way driver.switchTo().alert() does not work as the Alert does not show up. Seems like I have to add a listener but it means I have to change a lot of code.
I tried adding a listener from devtool but it looks cubersome and will change a lot of existing script in my tests.
  DevTools devTools = ((ChromeDriver) webDriver).getDevTools();
  devTools.createSession();

  // Listen for JavaScript dialogs (alerts, confirms, prompts)
  devTools.send(Page.enable());
  devTools.addListener(Page.javascriptDialogOpening(), dialog -> {
    System.out.println("Alert Text: " + dialog.getMessage());
    devTools.send(Page.handleJavaScriptDialog(true, null)); // Accept the alert
  });

Is there any other way?
